# How to init model in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking way to init model with empty value without ng-init or ugly code in controller (my form model is very huge and contains variable amount of fields).

Please to run sample http://jsfiddle.net/c9Q6Y/

"Serialize" link shows "{}" - empty model if input not touched, and {"name":""} if enter something to imput and clear it.

How to adjust AngularJS to init model fields as empty lines by default?

```
<div ng-app="">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
      text: <input name="input"  ng-model="user.name">     
   <div>
      <a ng-click="Serialize()">Serialize</a> 
      </div>
       {{serializedUser}}
   </form>
</div>

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.serializedUser = "";
    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.Serialize = function() {
        $scope.serializedUser = JSON.stringify($scope.user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle link is wrong.

Comment: Stewie, thanks for report. Fixed.

Comment: Why would you need empty models. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to process model object after angular, so I need to know what fields object contains even if it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you'd have to do it manually...

```
$scope.user = {prop1: '', prop2: '', prop3: 0, prop4: [] ...};
```

You could do something like:

```
$scope.resetUser = function() {
  $scope.user = {prop1: '', prop2: '', prop3: 0, prop4: [] ...};
};
```

And then at the bottom of your controller:

```
$scope.resetUser();
```

Another solution might be to return such a stub object from your factory.